# Project file could not be saved

Tags: install4j

We upgraded install4j from v5 to v6. However when we try to save the upgraded install4j project file, it gives an error saying:

```
Project could not be saved
Error saving configuration: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

The following error messages gets logged to install4j_error.log in %TMP% folder:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.invokeOnEDT(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.config.a.ab.c(ejt:269)
at com.a.b.b.q.a(ejt:41)
at com.install4j.config.q.c(ejt:231)
at com.install4j.config.q.a(ejt:220)
at com.install4j.config.m.d(ejt:235)
at com.a.b.c.b(ejt:143)
at com.install4j.gui.g.b(ejt:530)
at com.install4j.gui.g.a(ejt:59)
at com.install4j.gui.h.a(ejt:495)
at com.install4j.gui.h.call(ejt:492)
at com.ejt.framework.gui.ff.run(ejt:44)
at com.ejt.framework.gui.dr.run(ejt:352)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.sun.beans.finder.ConstructorFinder.findConstructor(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Statement.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Statement.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Statement$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.beans.Statement.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Expression.getValue(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.getValue(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.get(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(Unknown Source)
```

...

Comment: Can you try to isolate the offending screen or action by deleting elements on the Installer->Screens & Actions step?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion. I found the offending section. It was "labelFont" from below. Removing the "labelFont" void element fixed the problem.

```
<formComponent name="" id="6313" customizedId="" beanClass="com.install4j.runtime.beans.formcomponents.LabelComponent" enabled="true" commentSet="false" comment="" insetTop="" insetLeft="" insetBottom="" insetRight="" resetInitOnPrevious="false">
<serializedBean>
  <java class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
    <object class="com.install4j.runtime.beans.formcomponents.LabelComponent">
      <void property="labelFont">
    <object class="java.awt.Font">
      <string />
      <int>2</int>
      <int>10</int>
    </object>
      </void>
      <void property="labelText">
    <string>... wildcards.</string>
      </void>
    </object>
  </java>
</serializedBean>
<initScript />
<visibilityScript />
</formComponent>
```